# Change date-time to a single digit hour ending for dataframe in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I have a CSV file that has a column that has values like:

```
10/23/2018 11:00:00 PM
```

I want to convert these values strictly by time and create a new column which takes the *time* of the entry (11:00:00 etc) and changes it into an hour ending time.

Example looks like:

```
11:00:00 PM to 12:00:00 AM = 24,  12:00:00 AM to 1:00:00 AM = 1, 1:00:00 AM to 2:00:00 AM = 2 .....etc
```

Looking for a simple way to calculate these by indexing them based off this conversion.

My first pseudo code idea is to do something like grabbing the column df['Date'] and finding out what the time is:

```
file = pd.read_csv()
def conv(n):
    date_time = n.iloc[1,1]  #Position of the date-time column in file
    for i in date_time:
        time = date_time[11:] #Point of the line where time begins
```

Unsure how to proceed.

Comment: So are you trying to do `file.apply(conv)`? I think I get what you want to do, but I'm not sure what's the format of the input. Also, is the type of item in the Date column `datetime.datetime`, or is it string?

Comment: The input format is shown above. Each date looks like `10/23/2018 11:00:00 PM,....., 10/23/2018 5:00:00` PM, etc.... and they're all currently default object types.

Comment: Are the bins closed on the left? [11:00:00 PM to 12:00:00 AM) = 24, [12:00:00 AM to 1:00:00 AM) = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
import pandas as pd

data ='''
10/23/2018 11:00:00 PM
10/23/2018 12:00:00 AM
'''.strip().split('\n')

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date'])

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

#df['pad1hour'] = df['date'].dt.hour+1
#or
df['pad1hour'] = df['date'] + pd.Timedelta('1 hours')

# I prefer the second as you can add whatever interval e.g. '1 days 3 minutes'



print(df['pad1hour'].dt.time)
```

Comment: I tried using this but I get a 0 hour. I can't seem to get rid of it because I'd like a 1-24 hour system and this gives me 0-23.

Comment: Oh! Then change it to method first method:df['pad1hour'] = df['date'].dt.hour + 1
and print(df['pad1hour'])

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Gives me an `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` Is there any way to format the `df['pad1hour'] = df['date'] + pd.Timedelta('1 hours')` method? It works for the format but just needs adjusting.

Comment: Can you show a sample values of df['date'] and its dtype?

Answer (score 1):

You should convert to a `datetime` with `pd.to_datetime(df.your_col)` (your format will be automatically parsed correctly, though you can specify it to improve the speed) and then you can use the `.dt.hour` accessor.

```
import pandas as pd
# Sample Data
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-01-03', freq='30min')})

df['hour'] = df.date.dt.hour+1
print(df.sample(20))

                  date  hour
95 2018-01-02 23:30:00    24
66 2018-01-02 09:00:00    10
82 2018-01-02 17:00:00    18
80 2018-01-02 16:00:00    17
75 2018-01-02 13:30:00    14
83 2018-01-02 17:30:00    18
49 2018-01-02 00:30:00     1
47 2018-01-01 23:30:00    24
30 2018-01-01 15:00:00    16
52 2018-01-02 02:00:00     3
29 2018-01-01 14:30:00    15
86 2018-01-02 19:00:00    20
59 2018-01-02 05:30:00     6
65 2018-01-02 08:30:00     9
92 2018-01-02 22:00:00    23
8  2018-01-01 04:00:00     5
91 2018-01-02 21:30:00    22
10 2018-01-01 05:00:00     6
89 2018-01-02 20:30:00    21
51 2018-01-02 01:30:00     2
```

Comment: When I create something like: `df['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` followed by `df['Hour Ending'].date.dt.hour + 1` I get the `Series object has no attribute 'date' error.

Comment: @HelloToEarth That is because you created a column named `Hour`, so there is no column named `date`. (Notice I'm using the `.col_name` method of referencing columns). So the correct reference would be `df.Hour.dt.hour+1`, or equivalently `df['Hour'].dt.hour+1`

Comment: Glad it helped! I know it can be confusing with all of the similarly named accessors and column names with the `.` notation sometimes

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to do it:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv()
```

#### Case One: If you want to keep the date

```
file['New datetime'] = file['Date_time'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x) + timedelta(hours = 1))
```

#### Case Two: If you just want the time

```
file['New time'] = file['Date_time'].apply(lambda x: (pd.to_datetime(x) + timedelta(hours = 1)).time())
```

If you need the column's data type as string instead of Timestamp you can just do:

```
file['New time'] = file['New time'].astype(str)
```

To convert it to a readable string.

Hope it helps.